# Why doesn't CloudFront GZIP my HTML/JSP pages

Tags: caching, gzip, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ddos

I've configured CloudFront in front of my Elastic Beanstalk/load-balanced web application and the static content rule (Png images etc) are being caching and served GZIPPED.

However my JSP pages aren't being **Gzipped**.

Please note that I have explicitly set my default rule to not cache by setting the min TTL to 0, but it's probably un-necessary because my origin server isn't returning a Content-Length header for JSP pages, so it will never be cached anyway.

> CloudFront will only cache if...
>
> 1. Filetype is supported (text/html is)
> 2. Response is 1,000 -> 10,000,000 bytes (it is)
> 3. Content-Length header must be provided (it is **NOT**)
> 4. Content-Encoding must *not* be set (it is not)

So that explains why it's not being cached, fair enough.

But **why don't my HTML pages get GZIPPED**? FYI my HTML and JSP file extensions are all processed through the JSP processor.

[image: Network Diagnostics]

[image: Static Behavior (works)]

[image: Default Behavior (no GZIP)]

[image: Origin Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was right, until my page was modified to return the Content-Length response header, CloudFront did not cache nor GZIP the content.